# without passing arguments how compare funcation work

Tags: c, sorting, comparison, quicksort, qsort

I want to sort `struct` array but while understand the logic of compare function i stuck my confusion is how compare function is work when it call in `qsort()` function without passing argument

Using GCC on Code Block on windows:

***Code***

```
int compare(const void * a, const void * b);

struct cricketers
{
  int avrun;
  char name[30];
  int age;
  int notm;
}india[Max] = {
  122, "Sachin Tendulkar", 30, 67,
  97, "Virendra Sehwag", 35, 56,
  66, "Irfan Pathan", 32, 45,
  153, "Yusuf Pathan", 36, 21,
  101, "Yuvaraj Singh", 32, 45,
};

int main()
{
  int i;
  qsort(india, 5, sizeof(struct cricketers), compare);

  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    printf("Name : %s", india[i].name);
    printf("\nAge : %d", india[i].age);
    printf("\nTotal Test Matches played : %d", india[i].notm);
    printf("\nAverage Run : %d\n\n\n", india[i].avrun);
  }
  _getch();
  return 0;
}

int compare(const void * a, const void * b)
{
  return (*(int*)a - *(int*)b);
}
```

Comment: The `qsort` function internally calls `compare` and passes it the proper arguments. However, the way you implemented the `compare`, you get undefined behavior if you use it this way.

Comment: The `compare` function is passed two pointers which must be cast to pointers to `struct cricketers`. You can then compare members of the structs. Generally, you should *compare* the data, not subtract it, to prevent overflow. It looks as though you are trying to take a short-cut by taking advantage that the member you want to compare is the first member in the `struct`. It's terrible practice.

Comment: @Blaze please explain more

Comment: if i write variable=compare; what it mean

Comment: It's a _callback function_. It gets called by `qsort` not by you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the function `qsort` that internally calls the comparison function passing to it void pointers to two elements of the array.

According to the C Standard (6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers) the address of the first member of a structure is equal to the address of the whole object of the structure type.

> 15 Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units
>   in which bit-fields reside have addresses that increase in the order
>   in which they are declared.  **A pointer to a structure object,
>   suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is
>   a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa.
>   There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its
>   beginning**.

So the value for example of the parameter `a` casted to the type `int *` yields the address of the data member `int avrun` of the structure.

Nevertheless this expression `(*(int*)a - *(int*)b)` can invoke undefined behavior due to overfloating of signed integers.

I would write the comparison function the following way.

```
int compare( const void *a, const void *b )
{
    const struct cricketers *left  = ( const struct cricketers * )a;
    const struct cricketers *right = ( const struct cricketers * )b;

    return ( right->avrun < left->avrun ) - ( left->avrun < right->avrun ); 
}
```

Comment: please explain overfloating mean     and  return ( right->avrun < left->avrun ) - ( left->avrun < right->avrun );      is working like  return ( if ( right->avrun < left->avrun) ) - ( if ( left->avrun < right->avrun ));

Comment: @hirico The result of the expression can be for example too big that can be stored in an object of the type int.

Comment: return ( right->avrun < left->avrun ) - ( left->avrun < right->avrun ); is working like return ( if ( right->avrun < left->avrun) ) - ( if ( left->avrun < right->avrun ));

Comment: @hirico You may not use statements in expressions. The expression  ( right->avrun < left->avrun ) returns either 1, or 0. So if the expression returns 1 then the second expressions ( left->avrun < right->avrun ) returns 0 and the result is equal to 1 (1 - 0)